# NumPy stack or append array to array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, valueerror

I am starting with NumPy.

Given two `np.array`s, `queu` and `new_path`:

```
queu = [ [[0 0]
          [0 1]]
       ]

new_path = [ [[0 0]
              [1 0]
              [2 0]]
           ]
```

My goal is to get the following `queu`:

```
queu = [ [[0 0]
          [0 1]]
         [[0 0]
          [1 0]
          [2 0]]
       ]
```

I've tried:

```
np.append(queu, new_path, 0)
```

and

```
np.vstack((queu, new_path))
```

But both are raising

> all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

I didn't get the NumPy philosophy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your desired result is not a matrix since a matrix needs to have equal number of elements at all axis (e.g 3x2 - 3 rows with exactly 2 elements in each row)

Comment: Ok, I understand. I try to enumerate all possible way on a 2D matrix. I'll change my approach.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

```
In [73]: queu = np.array([[[0, 0],
                            [0, 1]]
                         ])
In [74]: queu.shape
Out[74]: (1, 2, 2)

In [75]: new_path = np.array([ [[0, 0],
                                [1, 0],
                                [2, 0]]
                             ])

In [76]: new_path.shape
Out[76]: (1, 3, 2)

In [81]: np.hstack((queu, new_path))
Out[81]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 0]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [741]: queu = np.array([[[0,0],[0,1]]])
In [742]: new_path = np.array([[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0]]])
In [743]: queu
Out[743]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1]]])
In [744]: queu.shape
Out[744]: (1, 2, 2)
In [745]: new_path
Out[745]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 0]]])
In [746]: new_path.shape
Out[746]: (1, 3, 2)
```

You have defined 2 arrays, with shape (1,2,2) and (1,3,2).  If you are puzzled about those shapes you need to reread some of the basic `numpy` introduction.

`hstack`, `vstack` and `append` all call `concatenate`.  With 3d arrays using them will just confuse matters.

Joining on the 2nd axis, which is size 2 for one and 3 for the other, works, producing a (1,5,2) array.  (This is equivalent to `hstack`)

```
In [747]: np.concatenate((queu, new_path),axis=1)
Out[747]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 0]]])
```

Trying to join on axis 0 (vstack) produces your error:

```
In [748]: np.concatenate((queu, new_path),axis=0)
....
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

The concatenation axis is 0, but dimensions of axis 1 differ.  Hence the error.

Your target is not a valid numpy array.  You could collect them together in a list:

```
In [759]: alist=[queu[0], new_path[0]]
In [760]: alist
Out[760]: 
[array([[0, 0],
        [0, 1]]), 
 array([[0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 0]])]
```

Or an object dtype array - but that's more advanced `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me how you've set up your `array`s, but from the sound of it, `np.vstack` should indeed do what you are look for:

```
In [30]: queue = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1]).reshape(2, 2)

In [31]: queue
Out[31]:
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1]])

In [32]: new_path = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0]).reshape(3, 2)

In [33]: new_path
Out[33]:
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0]])

In [35]: np.vstack((queue, new_path))
Out[35]:
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0]])
```